# Copy emulators from other PC

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I would like to copy Android emulators from one PC to another in order not to download them from Internet. I have AWD folder copied to new PC. How to tell new Android Studio to use these emulators? How to set path to them in Android Studio?

**Edit:**

After I copied emulators from other PC I got `Missing system image` error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you don't need to set the Path. `Android Studio` automatically picks if you copy your `<YOUR_EMULATOR_NAME>.avd` and `<YOUR_EMULATOR_NAME>.ini` files into your `~/.android/avd` folder.

`<YOUR_EMULATOR_NAME>.avd` is directory and it contains `.img` files and other files and `<YOUR_EMULATOR_NAME>.ini` is a text file and it contains `path`(is an absolute path to your `.avd`), `path.rel` (is a relative path to your `.avd`) and `target`.

I tried just now and it worked for me.

**Update:**

You need to copy system images and vendor images from your Android Library path mentioned below.

```
disk.systemPartition.initPath = /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-26/google_apis/x86//system.img

disk.vendorPartition.initPath = /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-26/google_apis/x86//vendor.img
```

Comment: I have `d:\AWD` folder with all emulators and `<YOUR_EMULATOR_NAME>.ini` in first PC. Where I should place this folder in other PC?

Comment: Can you find `.android` folder in your home directory?

Comment: Yes, I have copied images to .android/awd, edited ini files for correct path and got error described in UPD

Comment: You also need to update the paths in all `.ini` files inside `.avd` folder.

Comment: And, also copy system images from your other PC. Please check my updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Missing system image` hints for, that you have to install these system images with the SDK manager. Those "download" buttons should do the job - if not, then use the SDK manager to install the ones it demands.

The `kernel.path` and the `disk.systemPartition.initPath` in the `AVD`'s `hardware-qemu.ini` need to be adjusted to the Android `SDK`'s location, so that it will be able to boot them (else it will complain, just alike the sceenshot shows). I don't have any `disk.vendorPartition.initPath` here, so this probably isn't required. if any `hardware-qemu.ini` has such a value, also adjust this one.